# MongoDB data update method showing internal server error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, material-ui

I am using mongoDB as database in one of my reactjs project. But can't update/modify already uploaded data. When try to update my data it's showing an error. How this problem can be solved.

[image]

Front end

```
<TableBody>
       {
         appointment.map((appointment) => (
           <TableRow key={appointment._id}>
             <TableCell component="th" scope="row" align="center">
               {appointment.details.name}
             </TableCell>
             <TableCell align="center">{appointment.details.time}</TableCell>
             <TableCell align="center">
               <Select
                  value={action}
                  onChange={handleChange}
               >
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => setId(appointment._id)} value={"notVisited"}>Not Visited</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem onClick={() => setId(appointment._id)} value={"visited"}>Visited</MenuItem>
               </Select>
             </TableCell>
           </TableRow>
          ))
        }
 </TableBody>
```

handleChange Function

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAction(event.target.value);
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/modifyAppointmentByKey", {
        method: "post",
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({action: action, _id: id})
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log("modify done");
    })
}
```

Back end

```
app.post('/modifyAppointmentByKey', (req, res) => {
const _id = req.body._id;
const action = req.body.action;
client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
     const collection = client.db("doctorsPortal").collection("appointment");
     collection.updateOne({"_id": objectId(_id)}, {$set: action}, (err, result)=>{
         if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message:err});
         }
         else{
             console.log("done");
             res.send(documents);
         }
     })
     client.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you Able to get any data from the backend? If No, then I guess there is some problem while contacting the backend because of CORS policy.

Just try to use this middleware in your backend to give the permissions required-

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {        
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
     }
    return next();
});
```

Comment: Yes, I already used some data. And CORS policy is ok.